# Can't start an Intel Visual Fortran Project

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I have installed Visual Studio PRO 2019.  I am trying to test Intel Visual Fortran using "parallel_studio_xe_2020_cluster_edition_setup.exe". I'm getting a warning during this installation:

> Intel C++ compiler will not work because none of the supported environments is found on your computer

Then it has a long paragraph saying that Intel C++ compiler requires Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 or 2019, **which I have installed**. It allows me to open VS2019, but I don't have the option to create a Fortran project. It doesn't appear in the list. Help?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot or the exact error you have received.  Be sure Visual Studio 2019 is fully updated.  Edit your question and include this vital and required information instead of submitting a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then it has a long paragraph saying that Intel C++ compiler requires Microsoft visual studio 2017 or 2019 WHICH I HAVE INSTALLED.

You might have Visual Studio 2019 installed but the required components are not installed by default and must be selected separately.

Intel has indicated the following is the requirement to install Intel Parallel Studio 2020.

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2019* Professional Edition (or higher edition) or Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019* with 'Desktop development with C++' workload installed (NOTE! **Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 does not install the C++ component by default** - it must be selected under the Workloads view during installation. Refer to this article for details.)

Source: [Intel® C++ and Fortran Compilers for Windows* - Required Microsoft Development Software](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-parallel-studio-xe-compilers-required-microsoft-visual-studio)

It Is clear that you do not have the required C++ components installed otherwise you wouldn’t be told the installer cannot find the required supported environment.

You need to install the required Microsoft C++ Visual Studio 2019 components.

> 1. Open the Visual Studio Installer (See Windows Start or Windows Desktop)
> 2. For the installed version of Microsoft Visual Studio 2019*, select Modify
> 3. Under the Workloads view (shown below), select the checkbox to install the Desktop development with C++
> 4. To build applications to run on Windows XP*, check the Windows XP support for C++ component in Summary window
> 5. Select Modify
> 6. Continue with the installation

Source: [Installing Microsoft Visual Studio* 2019 for Use with Intel® Compilers](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installing-microsoft-visual-studio-2019-for-use-with-intel-compilers)

I can confirm Intel Parallel Studio 2020 supports the current version of Visual Studio 2019.